# Add new view to a controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a controller, `clients_controller`, with corresponding index, show, edit, delete, new & form views. Is there a way to create a new view like `clients/prospects.html.erb` that acts the same way as `clients/index.html.erb`, except is routed at `clients/prospects/`?

I've tried this:

```
match '/clients/prospects' => 'clients#prospects'
```

And some other things in `routes.rb`, but of course get the error "Couldn't find Client with id=prospects".

The goal here is basically to have a prospects view and a clients view, and by simply switching the hidden field to a 1, it (in the user's mind) turns a prospect into a client (it's a CRM-like app).

Comment: Did you add `match '/clients/prospects' => 'clients#prospects'` above `resources :clients`?

Comment: I did not, and that was solved it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a couple of things you need to do. First you need to put the your custom route **before** any generic route. Otherwise Rails assumes the word "prospects" is an id for the show action. Example:

```
get '/clients/prospects' => 'clients#prospects' # or match for older Rails versions
resources :clients
```

Also you need to copy / paste the index method in your ClientsController and name it prospects. Example:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @clients = Client.where(prospect: false)
  end

  def prospects
    @prospects = Client.where(prospect: true)
  end
end
```

Lastly, you need to copy the index.html.erb view and name the copy prospects.html.erb. In the example above you would have to work with the @prospects instance variable.

Comment: You don't have to copy the view if clients/prospects is **exactly** the same as clients/index. Instead, you can just add `render :template => 'clients/index'` after you load the prospects in the controller. You'll also have to name your variable @clients instead of @prospects if you want to use the same view. This also applies to gregates' answer.

Comment: Simply putting ```resources: clients``` below the route did the trick. I had it before it. I already had my methods set up, but did not do the ```.where```. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new action in clients controller named prospects. And then define a collection route in routes.rb for it as either resource full way. Or u directly use match as you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not wrong (although I'd change `match` to `get`, otherwise POST and DELETE requests to that url will also render your prospects view). Presumably you have

`resources :clients`

in your routes file? If so, what you have will probably work if you just move the line you quoted above the resources declaration -- the problem is that `/clients/prospects` matches the `show` route for the `clients` resource, so if it's defined first then that's the route that gets matched.

However, there's a more idiomatic way to define this route

```
resources :clients do
  collection do
    get :prospects
  end
end
```

See [Rails Routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for more

Also see migu's answer for what *else* needs to be done once the url is being routed correctly (though there are other things you can do  -- if you the two views are similar enough, you can reuse the view template, for example).